# HAML index of array element each loop

Tags: haml

So, i want to type the index of array element with each loop, i have tried

```
- @characters = ['t','e','s','t'];

- @characters.each do |character, index|
    %div{:class => "#{index}"} #{character}
```

but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-each), use [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) to also get the collection object's index:

```
- @characters = ['t','e','s','t']

- @characters.each_with_index do |character, index|
    %div{:class => index}= character
```

This will output:

```
<div class='0'>t</div>
<div class='1'>e</div>
<div class='2'>s</div>
<div class='3'>t</div>
```